# Explicitly implementing an interface with an abstract method

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

Here is my interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    bool Foo();
}
```

Here is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MyInterface {
    abstract bool MyInterface.Foo();
}
```

This is the compiler error:
*"The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item.*

How should I go on about explicitly implementing an abstract with an abstract method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't, basically. Not directly, anyway. You can't override a method which is explicitly implementing an interface, and you *have* to override an abstract method. The closest you could come would be:

```
bool MyInterface.Foo() {
    return FooImpl();
}

protected abstract bool FooImpl();
```

That still implements the interface explicitly *and* forces derived classes to actually provide the implementation. Are those the aspects you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I want to force classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass to implement Foo() but at the same time I want MyAbstractClass to explicitly implement MyInterface.Foo().  Right now this is what I'm doing in my code.

Comment: Though this is - as I believe - the only *direct* solution, it has a downside of a need to declare the same method(s) three times - the explicit interface implementation, then the protected abstract method and finally implementation in derived class. I'm curious, why can't it be done directly - now that MyAbstractClass is abstract, methods required by the interface might be treated as abstract methods of this class, ensuring their implementation in some derived class.

Answer (score 21):

You have to use an implicit implementation of the interface member instead of an explicit implementation:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MyInterface
{
    public abstract bool Foo();
}
```

Comment: I see. This is a much direct to the point.  Too bad I don't have any more upvotes left.

Answer (score 2):

An [abstract method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28VS.71%29.aspx) has no implementation, so it can't be used to explicitly *implement* an interface method.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious and at the same time obviously stating my ignorance of some C# syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In fact there is another option than using an abstract helper method which still keeps the implementation private:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MyInterface
{
  bool MyInterface.Foo() // must be overridden
  { throw NotImplementedException(); // never called
  }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyAbstractClass, MyInterface
{
  bool MyInterface.Foo() // overrides MyInterface.Foo
  { // Place your implementation here
  }
}
```

This pattern will also work if the interface has many methods and only some of them are redefined in the derived class. And, of course, you can also use this to override private interface implementations in general.

The major disadvantage is that Foo cannot be declared abstract in MyAbstractClass, so the compiler cannot ensure that the method is actually overridden. (It's a pity that abstract classes may not have incomplete interface implementations in C#.)

The advantage is that you save one calli instruction that is likely to cause CPU pipeline stalls. However, the impact is quite small, since the method cannot be inlined anyway because of the interface call. So I would recommend it only for performance critical cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to. Why not let the concrete implementation of the abstract class implement the member from the interface? It's the same thing really.

Comment: You mean like this?

public interface MyInterface { bool Foo(); }

public abstract class MyAbstractClass : MyInterface { }

public class ConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass { }


The problem is MyAbstractClass should implement the Foo() from MyInterface().

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "MyAbstractClass should implement the Foo() from MyInterface()". In your sample you want Foo() to be abstract so you're not implementing it. ConcreteClass will not compile if it does not provide an implementation to Foo().

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this

```
public interface SampleInterface
{
    void member1();
    void member2();
    void member3();
}

public abstract class Client2 : SampleInterface.SampleInterface
{
    public void member1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public abstract void member2();


    public void member3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Client3 : Client2
{
    public Client3()
    {

    }

    public override void member2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're implementing this interface implicitly, not explicitly. Read about differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jon's explanation: this is a way to bypass the problem instead of solving it directly and will work only in certain circumstances, but maybe someone will benefit from this idea.

If you plan to pass *all* (or at lest *most*) interface method calls to the derived class, you can do it in the following way:

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
    bool Foo();
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract MyInterface AsMyInterface();
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyInterface
{
    public override MyInterface AsMyInterface()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool Foo()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

...

MyAbstractClass c = new MyDerivedClass();
MyInterface i = c.AsMyInterface();
bool b = i.Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract all the interface methods that are implemented in a abstract class, even if you do not use them.

This particular case requires that you are implementing a hierarchy of 2 or more abstract classes, with a interface.

I was trying to implement a hierarchy in C# as well. I needed a Interface but I wanted a Abstract class, because most of the properties are the same for the interface. To do this I had to create a separate Abstract class, with the implementation, and then my Concrete classes, or in my case another abstract class, would inherit the Interface and the Abstract Class.

I do not think that this first one is a good example for many reasons, but I had to have it because the compiler would not allow FooBar to  implement Foo and then have another abstract class to inherit FooBar. So I had a abstract class with a abstract method bar(), and the interface with the bar() method.

```
public interface Foo { 
    bool bar();
    //other stuffs
}


public abstract class FooBar {
    public abstract bool bar();
    //Other stuffs
}

public abstract class FooBarAbstraction: FooBar, Foo {
     //other stuffs
     //Don't supply the interface and abstract here
}

public class FooBarConcrete: FooBarAbstraction {
    public override bool bar() {
        return true;
    }
   //other stuffs
}
```

This was my first attempt, then I got curious and started to think about it. I came across this solution.  The better solution.

```
public interface Foo { 
    bool bar();
    bool buzz();
    //other stuffs
}


public abstract class FooBar : Foo{
    public abstract bool bar();
    public abstract bool buzz();
    //Other stuffs
}

public abstract class FooBarAbstraction: FooBar {
     //other stuffs
     //Don't supply the interface and abstract here
     // override everything else
     public override bool buzz() {
         return false;
     }
}

public class FooBarConcrete: FooBarAbstraction {
    public override bool bar() {
        return true;
    }
   //other stuffs
}
```